# Filling in edge defined areas with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

My example is the following image, a section from a disparity map:

[image: Disparity map]

I am wanting to fill the gray area completely gray, and the the black area completely black. I know that I can get the edge with canny edge detection, yet I do not know how to fill those regions with two different colours.

I am wanting a method that is direct, such as a boundary with edges, as I have tried using kmeans segmentation however with K=3 the unwanted part still shows (and it also ruins the rest of the image).

Additional examples:

I am wanting to set the section outside the red line to black, and the section inside the line to gray (removing the blue region).

[image: Example 2]

In a larger example, which is my goal, I am wanting to set the region outlined in red to complete black, removing the dark gray regions which aren't defining much disparity. This would then apply to the other sections as well, removing overlapping "sections".

[image: Large example]

Comment: drawContour maybe help

Comment: Could you provide some more concrete definition of what exactly you consider "black" and what "grey"? There are more than 2 intensities in that image... for example, I may consider as black only those pixels with intensity 0 -- then it's a matter of doing a simple threshold. However, that may not be what you have on mind. | Which part is unwanted? Can you highlight it in another image?

Comment: @DanMašek I have updated the post, hopefully this illustrates what I want better

Comment: I think you should try this     *cv2.ximgproc.segmentation.createGraphSegmentation* it will give you a more realistic labelization of your image regarding the intensities.